# How to add a user to VC without them being connected

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

to expand on my question i want to add a user to a voice channel without them previously being in a voice channel
so i have lfg modal code:

```py
class crowed(ui.Modal, title='Player Invite'):
    game = ui.TextInput(label='Game Invitation', placeholder='Rocket league, Apex Legends, etc.', style= discord.TextStyle.short, required=True)
    type = ui.TextInput(label = 'Game mode', placeholder='duo, 1v1, squads, etc.', style= discord.TextStyle.short, required=True)
    info = ui.TextInput(label=' Game Description', placeholder='no revives, all snipers, etc.', style= discord.TextStyle.long, required=False, default=f'There was no given information provided.')
    region = ui.TextInput(label='Game Region',placeholder='North America, Europe, etc.', style= discord.TextStyle.short, required=True)
    

    async def on_submit(self, interaction: discord.Interaction):
        category_name = "Games"  
        category = discord.utils.get(interaction.guild.categories, name=category_name)
        vc_name = f"{self.game} - {interaction.user.display_name}"
        vc = await category.create_voice_channel(vc_name)
        chicken = discord.Embed(title= f'Description: {self.info}', timestamp= datetime.now(), type='rich', color=discord.Color.random())
        chicken.add_field(name=' <:gg:1116420203308396556> Game',value=f'{self.game}', inline=True)
        chicken.add_field(name=f' <a:PP:1116409338630770769> Game Mode',value=f' {self.type}', inline=True)
        chicken.add_field(name=f' <a:sq:1116423925430222968> Region Type',value=f'{self.region}', inline=True)
        chicken.add_field(name=' <a:ds:1095220553540968578> VC/Lobby Space', value=f'{len(vc.members)}/{vc.user_limit} members in VC right now!')
        chicken.set_footer(text='use /invite to create your own game invite!', icon_url='https://art.pixilart.com/c4ec72c5f32b864.gif')
        invite = await vc.create_invite(max_age=0, max_uses=0, unique=True)
        chicken.add_field(name=f'**{vc.name} | {vc.category}** ', value=f'**[Click here to join]({invite.url})** ', inline=True)
        chicken.set_author(name=f' {interaction.user.display_name} is looking for party members!', icon_url=f'{interaction.user.guild.icon}', url = 'https://discord.com/users/' + str(interaction.user.id))
        chicken.set_thumbnail(url=f'{str(random.choice(listc))}')
        await interaction.response.send_message(embed=chicken)
        await interaction.user.edit(voice_channel=vc)
        await vc.set_permissions(interaction.user,manage_members=True,move_members=True,moderate_members=True)
```

as you can see above i was doing `await interaction.user.edit(voice_channel=vc)` but it gives the error below. so how can i achieve this?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\ui\modal.py", line 188, in _scheduled_task
    await self.on_submit(interaction)
  File "c:\Users\trace\Desktop\MU LFG\lfg bot\lfg.py", line 37, in on_submit
    await interaction.user.edit(voice_channel=vc)
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 913, in edit
    data = await http.edit_member(guild_id, self.id, reason=reason, **payload)
  File "C:\Users\trace\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 745, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 400 Bad Request (error code: 40032): Target user is not connected to voice.
```

Comment: This is impossible to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not a feature and will most likely never be implemented by discord. This is a safety issue, you can only move people already in channels.

Comment: ok so since this seems impossible i just made a join to create VC, thanks for the help.